# Magento reset product list view all

Tags: magento

Magento Version 1.7.0.0

right i'm trying to reset the product list count to the default value when customer changes category.

e.g.

Customer visits - Category A
Default products shown - 16
Selects View All
Views all products
Navigates to - Category B
Shows All not 16.

I know there is a way to change this in toolbar.php but this is modifying a core file that i'm trying to avoid. Any way i can do this without editing a core file?

cheers
Andy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add that in your template file and it should do the trick :

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/session')->unsLimitPage();`

Hope it helps!